# Why can the number of zeros be no more than the number of delay elements in a signal flow network?

Tags: poles-zeros, delay

Let $N$  be the signal graph representation network of the system function (in rationale form) of a discrete-time LTI system.  For a network $N$  with
no loops, the impulse response is no longer than the total number of delay elements
in the network. From this, we conclude that if a network has no loops, then the system
function has only zeros (except for poles at $z = 0$), and the number of zeros can be no
more than the number of delay elements in the network.

Q: Why  can the number of zeros  be no
more than the number of delay elements in the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for a polynomial of degree $N$, the number of zeros (roots) is no more than $N$.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing preventing you from writing down an expression that has more zeros than poles.  In fact, a typical FIR filter may be designed as something like $$\sum_{n = -\frac{N-1}{2}}^{\frac{N-1}{2}} f(n) z^n$$
giving you a filter that's nice and symmetrical around zero delay.

The problem is, that in the physical world, $z$ is a *lead* operator -- it fetches samples *from the future*.  Since physicists stubbornly refuse to invent time machines for us, we have to make do with filters that only operate on past values of the input.

Thus, we only allow $z^{-n}$, and accept $z^0$ because we have an unspoken agreement that it means "the latest sample, with just a bit of delay".

Comment: +1; Just for the sake of completeness: transfer functions always have the same numbers of poles and zeros IF we also count poles and zeros at infinity and at the origin.